# C++ code cross compiling to ARM, runtime crash

Tags: c++, android, crash

I'm fixing a bug about android multimedia framework lower c++ lib.  When the code running to following position system goto crash.

```
if (((*pChar) >= _T('a')) && ((*pChar) <= _T('z'))) {
    nFrameTime++;
}

nFrameTime is int type;
pChar is wchar_t* type;
```

But when i modify the code to:

```
if (((*pChar) >= _T('a')) || ((*pChar) <= _T('z'))) {
    nFrameTime++;
}
```

Everything is OK.  I do not care about using "&&" or "||", I only want to know why that go to crash.  Anybody can give me some suggestions?

Comment: There's not nearly enough code shown to tell you what the problem is.  That change isn't causing this line to crash (OTOH that change is equivalent to `*pChar; if (true) {`)

Comment: @Ben Voight - Good point. It could be that the optimizer isn't bothering with the check, because the union of the two checks is the entire set of `wchar_t`.

Comment: Indeed. My crystal ball tells me that someone is reading a `wchar_t` from an unaligned address, which the ARM architecture generally frowns upon.

Comment: What is the exact definition or wording of the crash?  Is it an undefined address exception?  Data access exception?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `pChar` isn't pointing at valid data. That's the only thing in there that could really cause a crash (compiler bugs excepted).

The real mystery is why the changed version *isn't* crashing.

As to the answer to *my* question, it could be that when you change the code it modifies things just enough that the garbage in pChar happens to point to a valid memory location. Another possibility, as Ben Voigt pointed out in the comments, is that the check is being optimized away in the second version, because any value at all of `*pChar` will cause it to be `true`.

Comment: The crash may have something to do with *short-circuiting* of logical expressions.  The `||` has different short-circuiting rules than the `&&` operator.

Comment: Great thanks to everybody, at last i found the problem: running an armv6 version's so file on armv4 makes than crash.